# Syntax error Missing operator in my case statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got an error with the below SQL I wrote in ACCESS, where is my mistake? I've other when statements to add

```
UPDATE daily_inventory t0
SET 
t0.Type = CASE  
    WHEN t0.[item number] LIKE "*-FG-*" 
    THEN "Float"
END
```

[image]

Comment: Afaik there's no `case` in Access, you must use `iif` instead

Comment: Don't you want a WHERE clause instead? To update "*-FG-*" rows only, and else keep current values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access won't support `CASE` expression use `IIF()` instead :

```
UPDATE daily_inventory AS t0
     SET t0.[Type] = IIF(t0.[item number] LIKE "*-FG-*", "Float", '<whatever>')
```